# Find my location don't work (android 2.2)

Tags: android, google-maps, location

I tried to implement the code found in this link [location find](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/location/obtaining-user-location.html)

The truth is I want to get my location using network or GPS, ( I tested it on Network)

```
private Location getCurrentLocation(){
// Acquire a reference to the system Location Manager
LocationManager locationManager = (LocationManager) this.getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
// Define a listener that responds to location updates
LocationListener locationListener = new LocationListener() {
    public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
      // Called when a new location is found by the network location provider.

        mLatitude = location.getLatitude();
        mLongitude =  location.getLongitude();
        myGeoPoint = GeoTools.makeGeoPoint(mLatitude, mLongitude);
        mapController.animateTo(myGeoPoint);

    }

    public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) {}

    public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {}

    public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {}
  };

// Register the listener with the Location Manager to receive location updates
locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER, 0, 0, locationListener);
String locationProvider = LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER;
// Or use LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER

Location lastKnownLocation = locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(locationProvider);
if(lastKnownLocation==null){
     locationProvider = LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER;
    // Or use LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER

     lastKnownLocation = locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(locationProvider);    
}

return lastKnownLocation;
```

}

How to return the result:

```
myLocation = getCurrentLocation();
        if(myLocation != null)
        {
        mLatitude = myLocation.getLatitude();
        mLongitude =  myLocation.getLongitude();
        myGeoPoint = GeoTools.makeGeoPoint(mLatitude, mLongitude);
        mapController.animateTo(myGeoPoint);

        }else {         
            mLatitude =  36.859502;
            mLongitude = 10.168097;
            myGeoPoint = GeoTools.makeGeoPoint(mLatitude, mLongitude);
            mapController.animateTo(myGeoPoint);}
```

This wasn't the only code i tried and i dont found any result on a android 2.2 phone.

Any idea about how can i fix it

> i check most of the tutorials on the net!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a long research, I found my pleasur [Here](http://www.firstdroid.com/2010/04/29/android-development-using-gps-to-get-current-location-2/) :)

Hope this will help someone.

Answer (score 1):

First check whether did you add the following permissions or not.

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION"></uses-permission>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION"></uses-permission>
```

The second thing is that you should give some time to locate location info.You can do that using timer task or posDelayed.

```
private Location getCurrentLocation(){
// Acquire a reference to the system Location Manager
LocationManager locationManager = (LocationManager) this.getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
// Define a listener that responds to location updates
LocationListener locationListener = new LocationListener() {
    public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
      // Called when a new location is found by the network location provider.
        t.cancel();
        mLatitude = location.getLatitude();
        mLongitude =  location.getLongitude();
        myGeoPoint = GeoTools.makeGeoPoint(mLatitude, mLongitude);
        mapController.animateTo(myGeoPoint);

    }

    public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) {}

    public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {}

    public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {}
  };

locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER, 0, 0, locationListener);
Location lastKnownLocation;
Timer t = new Timer();

    t.schedule(new TimerTask() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                           this.cancel();
                           lastKnownLocation = locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(locationProvider);
                           if(lastKnownLocation==null){
                                     locationProvider = LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER;
                                     // Or use LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER

                             lastKnownLocation = locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(locationProvider);   
                             return lastKnownLocation;


             }

    },30000);

}
```

it will give you results after 30seconds.

Comment: well , i make some change on your code, and i made a timer, but still the same result